# Image upload type for Graphql magento2

Tags: file-upload, graphql, magento2

Is there any way to upload image using graphql without using base64 format in magento2

Answer (score 0):

```
public function uploadFile($fileData)
    {
        // convert base64 string to image and save as file on server.
        $uploadedFileName = "";
        $fileName = '';
        if (isset($fileData['name'])) {
            $fileName = $fileData['name'];
        } else {
            $fileName = rand() . time();
        }
        if (isset($fileData['filecontent'])) {
            $mediaPath = $this->fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
            $originalPath = 'ModuleName/Attachments/';
            $mediaFullPath = $mediaPath . $originalPath;
            if (!file_exists($mediaFullPath)) {
                mkdir($mediaFullPath, 0775, true);
            }
            /* Check File is exist or not */
            $fullFilepath = $mediaFullPath . $fileName;
            if ($this->fileDriver->isExists($fullFilepath)) {
                $fileName = rand() . time() . $fileName;
            }
            $fileContent = base64_decode($fileData['filecontent']);
            $savedFile = fopen($mediaFullPath . $fileName, "wb");
            fwrite($savedFile, $fileContent);
            fclose($savedFile);
            $uploadedFileName = "/" . $fileName ;
        }
        return $uploadedFileName;
    }
```

See more: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351629/101754

Comment: yes i am currently using this solution but if there is any other method for it,with out using base64